# Message: undefined method ` '

Tags: vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I'm attempting to have a mini multinet setup with these 3 vm's using the same box bento/ubuntu-18.04. Getting the following error

```
Line number: 19
Message: undefined method ` '
```

I have compared with another vagrant file I've used for the same setup and don't see what the difference or the issue is. 
Any insight on what this undefined method or variable is would be helpful.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"

  config.vm.define "admin" do |admin|
    admin.vm.hostname = "admin"
    admin.vm.network "private_network", type: "172.0.9.10"
      vb.memory = "2048"
  end

  config.vm.define "server01" do |server01|
    server01.vm.hostname = "server01"
    server01.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.0.9.11"
      vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.define "server02" do |server02|
    server02.vm.hostname = "server02"
    server02.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.0.09.12"
      vb.memory = "1024"
  end
end
```